# Highcharts line with null values

Tags: highcharts, null, line

I'm trying to create a line diagram (datetime x-axis) with null values.

```
var rawData = [{
    (...)
}, {
    "PointOfTime": 1424991600,
    "value": 6831.28806
}, {
    "PointOfTime": 1425078000,
    "value": null
}, {
    "PointOfTime": 1425164400,
    "value": null
}, {
    (...)
}];
```

Adjust the data from a json source to an array:

```
rawData.forEach(function (d) {
    var datetime = (d.PointOfTime + 3600) * 1000;
    data.push([datetime, parseFloat(d.value)]);
});
```

As stated in the following fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/1m5hpLef there are no lines, only bullets. Any suggestions? I need the PointOfTime to create the range of the x-axis, even they are empty.

// Edit: As displayed in the following figure, the values in the future are unknown and not 0, therefore I would like to set them to null.

[image: Example Picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition, which check if your value is null. If yes then push this, instead of call parseFloat(null).

```
rawData.forEach(function (d) {
    var datetime = d.PointOfTime * 1000;
    if(d.value!==null)
        data.push([datetime, parseFloat(d.value)]);
    else
         data.push([datetime, null]);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/1m5hpLef/

Comment: Wow thanks, my fault. I've searched the error somewhere in the Highcharts config!